# Default implementation for trait function that returns an associated type

Tags: rust, types, iterator, traits

I'm struggeling to define a default implementation for my trait function that returns an iterator.

I have defined a trait (`Labels`) with two function (`labels_vec` and `labels_iterator`).
I also have a struct (`NumberThing`) that implements that trait. See the little example below:

```rust
use std::{iter::Map, ops::RangeInclusive};

trait Labels {
    type Iterator: Iterator<Item = String>;

    // This trait function has a default implementation.
    fn labels_vec(&self) -> Vec<String> {
        vec!["default".to_string()]
    }

    // Can this trait function also have a default implementation? How?
    fn labels_iterator(&self) -> Self::Iterator;
}

struct NumberThing {
    max: u8,
}

impl Labels for NumberThing {
    type Iterator = Map<RangeInclusive<u8>, fn(u8) -> String>;

    fn labels_iterator(&self) -> Self::Iterator {
        (0..=self.max).map(|number| number.to_string())
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let number_thing = NumberThing { max: 3 };
    let labels_from_iterator: Vec<String> = number_thing.labels_iterator().collect();
    println!("labels from iterator: {labels_from_iterator:?}");
    println!("labels from vec: {:?}", number_thing.labels_vec());
}
```

How do I add a default implementation for `labels_iterator`?

Comment: I am not sure using associated type is the correct way. You cannot (default) implement returning the associated type because is not known at compile time. How could you implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this.

Well, if you really want, then you can, on nightly, by forwarding the logic to another type... But don't do this, please.

```rust
#![feature(associated_type_defaults)]

use std::{iter::Map, ops::RangeInclusive};

trait LabelsIterator<This: ?Sized> {
    type Iterator: Iterator<Item = String>;
    fn labels_iterator_impl(this: &This) -> Self::Iterator;
}

trait Labels {
    type IteratorImpl: LabelsIterator<Self> = DefaultLabelsIterator;
    
    fn max(&self) -> u8;

    fn labels_iterator(&self) -> <Self::IteratorImpl as LabelsIterator<Self>>::Iterator {
        Self::IteratorImpl::labels_iterator_impl(self)
    }
}

enum DefaultLabelsIterator {}

impl<This: ?Sized + Labels> LabelsIterator<This> for DefaultLabelsIterator {
    type Iterator = Map<RangeInclusive<u8>, fn(u8) -> String>;

    fn labels_iterator_impl(this: &This) -> Self::Iterator {
        (0..=this.max()).map(|number| number.to_string())
    }
}

struct NumberThing {
    max: u8,
}

// impl LabelsIterator<NumberThing> for NumberThing {
//     type Iterator = Map<RangeInclusive<u8>, fn(u8) -> String>;

//     fn labels_iterator_impl(this: &Self) -> Self::Iterator {
//         (0..=this.max).map(|number| number.to_string())
//     }
// }

impl Labels for NumberThing {
    // type IteratorImpl = Self;
    
    fn max(&self) -> u8 {
        self.max
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let number_thing = NumberThing { max: 3 };
    let labels_from_iterator: Vec<String> = number_thing.labels_iterator().collect();
    println!("labels from iterator: {labels_from_iterator:?}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't need to have to use `this.max` in my default implementation; I wasn't clear about that in my question. It makes your code a bit more complicated than need be. For completeness sake I will post an answer with the code snippet I ended up with (since it doesn't fit in a comment here). You set me on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: You say: "But don't do this, please." Can you elaborate? Why shouldn't I? Is this too ugly?

Comment: @michel404 Well, you _can_ if course if you want, but this is ugly, unclear and is IMHO worse than just reimplementing the default method.

Comment: Thats fair enough!

Answer (score 0):

Only if the associated type provides some way to construct itself, for example by implementing the `Default` trait:

```
trait Labels {
    type Iterator: Iterator<Item = String> + Default;

    fn labels_iterator(&self) -> Self::Iterator {
        Self::Iterator::default()
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem all that useful. If you want to do more complex things with the type in default impls, an associated type might not be the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Chayim Friedman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76697595/782416) put me on the right track. For future reference will I put the code I ended up with below.

Even though the code snippet uses the rust nightly channel, it is easily modified to get it to work in the stable channel as well.

```rust
#![feature(associated_type_defaults)]

use std::{iter::Map, ops::RangeInclusive, vec::IntoIter};

trait Labels {
    // Only this line requires `#![feature(associated_type_defaults)]`.
    // In the stable channel (1.71) this solution is also possible,
    // just add a line like this one to each `Labels` implementation
    // that relies on the default implementation of `labels_iterator`.
    type IteratorImpl: LabelsIterator = DefaultLabelsIterator;

    // This trait function can have a default implementation.
    fn labels_vec(&self) -> Vec<String> {
        vec!["default vec impl".to_string()]
    }

    // This trait function now also has a default implementation! :-D
    fn labels_iterator(&self) -> <Self::IteratorImpl as LabelsIterator>::Iterator {
        Self::IteratorImpl::labels_iterator_impl()
    }
}

trait LabelsIterator {
    type Iterator: Iterator<Item = String>;
    fn labels_iterator_impl() -> Self::Iterator;
}

enum DefaultLabelsIterator {}

impl LabelsIterator for DefaultLabelsIterator {
    type Iterator = IntoIter<String>;

    fn labels_iterator_impl() -> Self::Iterator {
        vec!["default iter impl".to_string()].into_iter()
    }
}

struct NumberThing {
    max: u8,
}

impl Labels for NumberThing {
    // NumberThing now relies on the default implementations of the trait functions.
    // Uncomment the lines below to override with custom implementations using `self.max`.

    // type IteratorImpl = NumberThingIterator;

    // fn labels_vec(&self) -> Vec<String> {
    //     (0..=self.max).map(|number| number.to_string()).collect()
    // }

    // fn labels_iterator(&self) -> <Self::IteratorImpl as LabelsIterator>::Iterator {
    //     (0..=self.max).map(|number| number.to_string())
    // }
}

enum NumberThingIterator {}

impl LabelsIterator for NumberThingIterator {
    type Iterator = Map<RangeInclusive<u8>, fn(u8) -> String>;

    // Using NumberThingIterator requires you to override the default implementation `labels_iterator`.
    // This cannot be enforced by the compiler, which is sad :-(
    fn labels_iterator_impl() -> Self::Iterator {
        panic!("override default `labels_iterator`")
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let number_thing = NumberThing { max: 3 };
    let labels_from_iterator: Vec<String> = number_thing.labels_iterator().collect();
    println!("labels from iterator: {labels_from_iterator:?}");
    println!("labels from vec: {:?}", number_thing.labels_vec());
}
```